# STM32 DAC maximum voltage cutoff

Tags: stm32, dac

I am trying to understand DAC operation on STM32 nucleo-L476RG. 
I am running a test script which iteratively changes DAC input from 0 to 4095, raising the output voltage from 0V to 3.3V, as you can see in the image.
DAC is tuned to use a buffer and has a trigger ON.

[image: without led]

However, when I am adding a load (simple blue LED),  the maximum output values over 3.1V are never reached and being cut off.

[image: with led]

I would be really grateful if someone could explain such a behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

> I would be really grateful if someone could explain such a behaviour.

Put a serial resistor with that LED.

Otherwise, the output is clamped by the LED.

Comment: woof. nailed it.